# Bootstrap carousel controls append carousel id to address instead of going to next slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have no clue why this isn't working. The id of my carousel is appended to the address of the webpage, I understand this has been an issue for people when they have not included the 'bootstrap.js' file but I believe I have.

Can someone please help identify what is happening? The frustration is real.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="First Web App">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript">

    <title>First Web App</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/home.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <script src="/js/home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="/home.html">Home</a>
        </div>

        <div class="main">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="500">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="/assets/todo.jpg" alt="todo" width="80%" height="40%">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Todo List</h3>
                            <p>Get your life together!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="/assets/money.jpg" alt="money" width="80%" height="40%">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Make Money</h3>
                            <p>Begin increasing now!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <h1>My First Heading</h1>
            <p>My first paragraph.</p>
            <div id="printLoop">
                <script>printTest();</script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data-* attributes have been replaced with data-bs-* in Bootstrap 5. So for Bootstrap 5, the code will be like this-

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="First Web App">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript">

    <title>First Web App</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/home.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="/home.html">Home</a>
        </div>

        <div class="main">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="500">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" alt="todo" width="80%" height="40%">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Todo List</h3>
                            <p>Get your life together!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" alt="money" width="80%" height="40%">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Make Money</h3>
                            <p>Begin increasing now!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <h1>My First Heading</h1>
            <p>My first paragraph.</p>
            <div id="printLoop">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks a lot, that has fixed it. Maybe I switch back to BS4 for more resources haha.

Comment: Please mark it as correct answer. So that others get help from it.